# activeX keep running in facebook app

Tags: facebook, activex

I want to create a FB app that uses ActiveX.
Is there a way to make the ActiveX running after the user left the app page and went to some other FB page?

Comment: Do you really want to use ActiveX? You would limit your users to IE even though Facebook supports all major browsers.

Comment: Right, I should have write add-on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to make the ActiveX running after the user left the app page and went to some other FB page?

You can substitue “ActiveX” here with “any kind of plugin content” easily, and the answer still remains the same as it has for ages on the web:

If the page it is contained in is unloaded, the plugin content will of course stop playing.

Within facebook.com, your only option is to open a popup and have your plugin content play within that window.

Comment: 10xs CBroe. I don't have a lot of experience with FB apps - can u pls write a bit more about the FB popup?

Comment: I’m not talking about an “FB popup”, but just a normal popup – those you open via JavaScript with window.open(…)